# Проблемы с кодировкой в базе данных mysql в сочетании с php

Tags: php, mysql

В текущем состоянии в базе данных хранится это `Ð”ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ` (хотя должно быть написано `Денис`).

Настройка таблицы указана кодировка `utf8_unicode_ci`.
В настройках кода PHP также

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8")
mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

При выводе из базы данных на HTML-страничку данные отображаются правильно.
Почему в базе неправильное отображение через phpMyAdmin также через консоль, сплошная крякозябрина.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И вот еще такая вот магия, если я возьму сообщение из контакта допустим написанное на русском, вставлю через php сценарий в базу, то отображается корректно, но если я это сделаю через Ubuntu собственными ручками, тобишь вобью в форму собственными ручками с клавиатуры русскую надпись, то снова расчудесные крякозябры.

Comment: Итого помогло . Вставить в php код mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему в базе неправильное отображение через phpMyAdmin также через консоль, сплошная крякозябрина.

Потому что в таблицах лежат данные в `utf8`, в то время как в определении таблиц стоит умолчательное `latin1`. Убедиться в этом можно, введя команду

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE MyGuests;
```

Когда phpMyAdmin пытается рабтать правильно, запрашивая у БД данные в той кодировке, в которой собрался их выводить, БД пытается перекодировать русский текст из latin1 в utf8, и мы получаем `Ð”ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ`.

Неправильное решение со `skip-character-set-client-handshake` выдает данные как есть, не перекодируя их. Но это, разумеется, кривой костыль. При первой же попытке поискть данные или отсортировать их, результаты ОЧЕНЬ сильно удивят.

Необходимо выставить таблицам адекватную кодировку. Если БД еще не живая, то удалить таблицы, задать дефолтную кодировку для database,

```
ALTER DATABASE aliendatabase CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

создать таблицы заново и начать работу с чистого листа. Просто "в лоб" поменять кодировку, сделать `alter table` не получится - после этой команды mysql добросовестно перекодирует лежащие данные в вид `Ð”ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ`, точно так же, как она сейчас это делает при выдаче, **но уже насовсем**.

Если база "живая", можно воспользоваться [инструкцией](http://phpfaq.ru/charset#repair), но перед этим обязательно сделать бэкап.

Comment: Спасибо, преогромное, все доступно и понятно. Заработало после удаления таблицы и создания базы данных с нуля , с указанием ей кодировки в utf8 . Тогда появляется вопрос, как же в конфиге mysql указать чтобы при создании БД или таблицы, по умолчанию кодировка выставлялась в UTF8.  
[client]  
default-character-set=utf8  

[mysql]  
default-character-set=utf8  
[mysqld]  
character_set_server=utf8  
collation_server=utf8_general_ci  
init-connect='SET NAMES

Comment: Так же появился еще один вопрос, как добавить возможность писать в клиенте mysql в терминале на русском. Для пояснения я могу в чистом терминале писать в русской кодировке, но в клиенте mysql не могу, как добавить этакую возможность?

Comment: Помогло, но только если ручками вставлять в mysql, через phpadmin, но если через сценарий php, то к сожалению все также, все те же нанавистные крякозябры...

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка при вставке тоже должна быть UTF-8. Вероятно, кодировка php файла не UTF-8.

Comment: Кодировка самого php файла, тоже UTF-8, все в этой кодировке, и таблица в базе, и сама база, все перепробовал, и когда выводишь в коде php, на самой странице выдает так же в UTF-8 , если записать напрямую через консоль российскими символами, тогда нормально отобразиться. Через php скрипт почему то нет. Перепробовал все, изменил кодировку базы, таблиц на UTF-8 , сохранял в этой же кодировке скрипт, все равно крякозябры...

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким способом. Добавил в конфиг `my.cnf` такую строчку:

```
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Если есть варианты получше, то я готов выслушать.

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло проставление кодировки после подключения.

```
mysqli_set_charset($your_db_connection, 'utf8');
```

Не ругайте, я знаю что mysqli уже не используют давно :)

[пример как проставить кодировку для pdo](https://karashchuk.com/PHP/PDO_mysql_utf8/)

> Первый вариант:
>
> ```
> new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$DB_NAME;charset=utf8;", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
> ```
>
> Второй вариант, как назначить использовать UTF-8 по умолчанию в MySQL:
>
> ```
> new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$DB_NAME;", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Спасло вот это  my.cnf (my.ini):

```
[mysqld]
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

взял тут https://gahcep.github.io/blog/2013/01/05/mysql-utf8/